# How to list the user's History from Youtube?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-api

I have been using this [library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API) for accessing youtube. I want to list the user's history from youtube.I have googled it but couldn't find an example for this Youtube API V3.

In the code below I was able to list the feed from User's home.

```
    public void GetRecommended(ref List<string> videoList)
    {
        YouTubeService youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = GoogleCredentials.apiKey,
            Authenticator = this.authenticator
        });
        // Create the request
        ActivitiesResource.ListRequest listRequest = youtube.Activities.List("contentDetails");
        listRequest.Home = true;
        listRequest.MaxResults = 10;

        // Fetch the response
        ActivityListResponse listResponse = listRequest.Execute();

        foreach (var item in listResponse.Items)
        {
            videoList.Add(item.ContentDetails.Upload.VideoId);
        }

    }
```

How can I list the user's history from Youtube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) request.

In the response, [contentDetails.relatedPlaylists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists) will give you playlists ids for "likes", "favorites", "uploads", "watchHistory" and "watchLater".

Then you can call [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with setting [playlistId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) paramater to those ids to iterate through videos.

Comment: Thanks..I tried it using google api explorer and I got all the playlist ids.But the user's history is private by default,so I think we can't list the history.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the history public?I have searched in the youtube settings page but couldn't find one.